# How is this question primarily opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I just noticed that the question [When unplugging a USB external hard drive, is it safer to unplug the cable from the computer, or from the external hard drive?](https://superuser.com/q/1096796/116475) had been closed as "primarily opinion-based". Since no comment were left regarding the closure, I am asking on meta: how is this question primarily opinion-based? I have no idea why an answer would be opinion-based.

---

Here is a copy of the question:

> [When unplugging a USB external hard drive, is it safer to unplug the
>   cable from the computer, or from the external hard
>   drive?](https://superuser.com/q/1096796/116475)
>
> When unplugging a USB external hard drive, is it safer to unplug the
>   cable from the computer first, or from the external hard drive?
>
> [image]
>
> I am asking as I saw an EHD died right after the USB cable had been
>   unplugged from it (the cable had been disconnected from the EHD
>   first).
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2):

I feel it's on topic, and not too opinion based; from experience, it makes a small difference, and is a valid question. I voted to reopen it.

Comment: Yes it's part of the topic of questions, but is the scope right? What makes a small difference?

Comment: @random Small difference in how you unplug hard drives, not the question. I feel the scope is right, as it deals with computers, especially in a home setting